# In JavaScript, what is the scope of a function declared within the condition of an if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope, expression, type-coercion

I recently had an interview question where I was shown this block of code (without the answer) and asked what would be printed to the console:

```
var i = 1;

if(function f(){}) {
  i += typeof f;
}

console.log(i);

// prints "1undefined"
```

I understand that typeof returns a string. Implicit type conversions combines the string from the typeof evaluation and the number into '1undefined'. However, I thought it would print '1function'.

What I don't completely understand, is why f is not in scope?

Is this not even a scope issue? Is the function declaration solely a Logical expression that gets evaluated to true as part of the if statement, and then no longer exist in any scope?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function is declared in the parentheses and is not passed down. Inside of the parentheses, you can use it.

Comment: The function name in that case is not supposed to be bound into the enclosing scope. In some old browsers, it was (erroneously), but I don't think that's been true for a lot of years. The function name is only bound *inside* the function, so outside there's no symbol `f`.

Comment: @Rojo no, it's not bound externally (to the function itself) at all.

Answer (score 2):

`f` is not in scope because it is an *inline named function expression*. It is not a *function declration*. The differences are subtle but important -

```js
// declaration
function f () { ... }

// named function expression
const foo = function f () { ... }

// named arrow expression
const f = () => { ... }

// unnamed arrow expression
() => { ... }
```

The semantics of `if` help us understand -

```
if (<expression>) {
  <consequent>
} else {
  <alternative>
}
```

As you can see, the conditional supplied to an `if` statement must be an *expression*. You cannot declare a variable in an expression. This includes function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The function statement is inside parentheses. This makes it a function *expression* and not a function *declaration*.

The variable `f` only exists *inside* the function.

```
(function f(){ /* i.e. here */ })
```

Outside the function there is no `f`, so you get `undefined` as you would for any other variable that doesn't exist in the current scope.

```js
console.log(typeof f);
```